# Returning a value from an enum

Tags: java

I have the following enum, it contains label and field values. I would like to return the field by passing in the label name.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

```
public enum Table (
   NAME("name", "FULL_NAME");

   public final String label;
   public final String field;

   private Table(String label, String field) {
   this.label = label;
   this.field = field;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's actually trivial, add a static method `public static String fieldByLable(String label) {  String result = null; for(Table i: Table.values()) { if( i.lable.equals(label) ) { result = i.field; break;}  } retrurn result; }` and then simply `String value = Table.fieldByLable("name")`; In any case, you need [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) forget about enum, for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add method `getField` to your enum

```
public enum Table (
   NAME("name", "FULL_NAME");

   public final String label;
   public final String field;

   private Table(String label, String field) {
   this.label = label;
   this.field = field;
   }

   public static String getField(String label) {
     String result = null;
     for(Table t : Table.values()) {
       if(t.label.equals(label) {
         result = t.field;
         break;
       }
     }
     return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to return result